# Retrieve specific datarow in C# Datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a datatable in C# called "table" that looks like the following:.

```
 ID   Value
 10    A
 20    B
 30    C
```

(It really has about 1200 rows, but I tried to simplify it)
My goal is to be able to print specific rows in this datatable.  For example, if I would like to print the second row (row index 1) I would use the following:

```
Response.Write(table.Rows[1]["Value"].ToString());
```

This prints out the value "B" which is what I want, but is there a way to use the "ID" column to print that specific value instead of using the row index of 1.  I would like to be able to link ID 10 and Value B together somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If ID isn't setup as a PK (or you want to query another field), you could use a Linq query

```
var chosenRow = (from row in table.AsEnumerable()
                    where row.Field<int>("ID") == 10
                    select row).First();
```

`chosenRow` is the first `DataRow` object that meets the criteria set in the `where` clause. So you could just:

```
Response.Write(chosenRow["Value"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

If `ID` is defined as the *primary key*, this should look up `B` by its `ID` key:

```
Response.Write(table.Rows.Find(20).["Value"].ToString());
```

Comment: ID is another data column in the table.

Answer (score 0):

you can loop trough your datatable using for each, and when the ID equals 10, then you do what you want

would be something like this:

```
for each row as datarow in datatable.rows
   if row.Items["ID"] = 10 Then
    //do something
   end if
```